# Mark "deleted" instead of physical deletion with Castle ActiveRecord

Tags: nhibernate, activerecord, castle

In my current project, we got a rather unusual request(to me). The client wants all the deletion procedure to mark a flag instead of physically delete the record from the database table. It looks pretty easy at the first glance. I just have change

```
public void DeleteRecord(Record record)
{ 
    record.DeleteAndFlush();
}

public IList GetAllRecords()
{
    Record.FindAll().ToList();
}
```

To

```
public void DeleteRecord(Record record)
{ 
   record.Deleted = true;
   record.UpdateAndFlush();
}

public IList GetAllRecords()
{
    Record.FindAll().Where(x=>x.Deleted==false).ToList();
}
```

But as after I get a bit of time and think though again. I found that this little change would cause a huge problem in my cascade settings. As I am pretty new to the Active Record business. I wouldn't trust myself to simply change all the CascaeEnum.Delete to CascadeEnum.SaveUpdate. So, I am looking some input here.

1) Is the mark a flag instead of physical requirement a common one?

2) If the answer to question 1 is Yes, then I believe there is something built-in in NHibernate to handle this. Can someone tell me what is the right approach for this kind of problem?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as Soft Deletes and it is very common. There is some debate about the best practice - check out this recent blog post: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/30/avoid-soft-deletes.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. it feels good to find that even big names such as ayende has similar concern as mine :)

Answer (score 2):

This is quite common and called "[soft delete](http://databaserefactoring.com/IntroduceSoftDelete.html)". [Here's an implementation](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/09/06/soft-deletes.aspx) of this for NHibernate.

Comment: Thanks Mauricio, I tried to mark your reply as answer but the system only allows one answer. So I have to go chronically and cbp's reply is about 1 minute early. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: So here's an upvote to at least give you some of the *rep* of an accept, if not the tick itself :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a relatively common request and it's sometimes implemented for (at least) two reasons:

1. *Auditing and history* - Marking a row as deleted rather than physically deleting it means the information is still available if needed (including recovery of information if, for example, you accidentally delete the wrong customer).
2. *Performance* - I've seen systems that batch up deletes with this method so they can be performed physically at a quiet time. I'm doubtful this is needed with modern DBMS' but I can see how it might have been so in the past if you wanted to avoid cascaded deletes on severely overloaded systems (of course, you shouldn't *be* running on such a system in the first place). Oracle 8 introduced a feature like this where you could drop columns in this manner and it would only physically remove them when you asked - you couldn't use the column at all even though the information had not yet been removed fully. Granted removal of a column is more intensive than removal of a row but it may still help.